# Perl 2x2 array addition using Subroutines and Reference

Tags: perl

My question in Perl is:
Define 2x2 arrays using anonymous lists. Pass the arrays to a subroutine and add them together. Return a reference to sum array and print the values from the main part of the program.

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

my @array = ([1,2],[4,5]); 

my $refarray = \@array;

print sumarray($refarray);

sub sumarray

{

 $refarray = shift;

 foreach (@{$refarray})

 {

  $refarray = ($refarray[0]->[0]+$refarray[1]->[0],$refarray[0]->[1]+$refarray[1]->[1]);

 }

 return $refarray;

}
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
I am getting the output as 0.
```

If I use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` I will get the error message as

```
Global symbol "@refarray" requires explicit package name at line 23.
Global symbol "@refarray" requires explicit package name at line 23.
Global symbol "@refarray" requires explicit package name at line 23.
Global symbol "@refarray" requires explicit package name at line 23.
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: How did you get that output? That code will not even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few problems with your code: -

- First, in your for-loop, you are modifying your reference `$refarray` which you should not do.
- Second, `$refarray[0]->[0]` will not compile. Since `$refarray` is a reference to an array, you should either use its 1st element using arrow: - `$refarray->[0][0]`, or you need to de-reference it before using the way you are using: - `$$refarray[0]->[0]`.

Having said that, I think you should replace your `subroutine` with this one: -

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ([1,2],[4,5]); 
my $refarray = \@array;

my $sum = sumarray($refarray);
print $sum->[0], $sum->[1];

sub sumarray {
    my $ref = shift;
    return [$ref->[0][0] + $ref->[1][0], $ref->[0][1] + $ref->[1][1]];
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
5 7
```

Comment: The question asks for an arrayref, the comma was probably an attempt to do this (though he's making an array rather than an arrayref).

Comment: According to the question, I cannot understand whether the output must be 3,9 or 5,7.Confused.

Comment: @user1613245. I think it expects `5 7`. Didn't got it completely first time. But I think you have already got 2 answers for that :) The idea was that, your were using your reference like an `array` instead of `reference`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $r = sumarray([1,2],[3,4]);
print $r->[0], " ", $r->[1], "\n";

sub sumarray {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return [
        $a->[0]+$b->[0],
        $a->[1]+$b->[1]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Would be better if it has `use strict`.

Answer (score 2):

It could be expressed very simply with a combination of the list operations **sum** (from the core module [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil)) and [**map**](http://p3rl.org/map).

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'sum';

sub sum_square {
    my @arrays = @_;
    return [ map {sum @$_} @arrays ];
}

say join ', ' => @{ sum_square([1,2], [4,5]) };
```

**Output**:

```
3, 9
```

Since this is Perl, it could be expressed in a more compact way.

### Shortification

```
sub sum_square { [ map {sum @$_} @_ ] }
say join ', ' => @{ sum_square([1,2], [4,5]) };
```

### Shortification<sup>2</sup>

```
say join ', ' => map {sum @$_} [1,2], [4,5];
```

### Edit: sum the other way round

If the function should be a column sum instead of a line sum, this modification should do the trick (iterate over the indices of the first array):

```
sub sum_square {
    my @arrays = @_;
    return [ map { my $i = $_;          # $i: all indices of the first array
        sum map $_->[$i] => @arrays     # sum over all $i-th values of @arrays
    } 0 .. $#{$arrays[0]} ];
}
```

Output:

```
5, 7
```